# How can I apply a different style to an element with an extra class in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to SASS and I'm trying to apply a style change to the div element with the active class. Here's my html

```
<div class="RatingSelector">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <div class="circle">2</div>
    <div class="circle active">3</div>
    <div class="circle">4</div>
    <div class="circle">5</div>
</div>
```

Here's the SASS code

```
.circle {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: $dark-blue;
  @include flexbox(center);
  color: $medium-grey;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background: $orange;
    color: $white;
    @include transition-ease;
  }

  &.active {
    background: white;
  } }
```

I'd like the background to be white when the div includes the active class. I know this is really basic, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I tried your code in a JSFiddle and it works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/8nhmgqs9/

Comment: Are you using React and SCSS module for the forntend? Just check in the inspector whether this active class is there in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using React and SCSS. Ok so that means the code is correct but my SASS implementation isn't quite right.

Comment: Yup. Is your scss files saved as `styles.module.scss` ? if so you should call the styles like `className={styles.active}`.

Answer (score -1):

You can style to the active class by going out of the style of circle scope , like this :

```
.circle {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: $dark-blue;
  @include flexbox(center);
  color: $medium-grey;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background: $orange;
    color: $white;
    @include transition-ease;
  }
 }
.active {
    background: white;
  }
```

Comment: A) that's not correct and B) this does not change anything meaningful

Comment: Why isn't is correct ?

Comment: `.circle .active` doesn't match an element that has both classes - the space is wrong. And: pulling this out of the other rule doesn't do anything useful here. The SCSS code posted by the OP is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you ! Understood the problem .